# Kubernetes Engine: Node keeps getting unhealthy and rebooted for no apparent reason

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

My Kubernetes Engine cluster keeps rebooting one of my nodes, even though all pods on the node are "well-behaved". I've tried to look at the cluster's Stackdriver logs, but was not able to find a reason. After a while, the continuous reboots usually stop, only to occur again a few hours or days later.

Usually only one single node is affected, while the other nodes are fine, but deleting that node and creating a new one in its place only helps temporarily.

I have already disabled node auto-repair to see if that makes a difference (it was turned on before), and if I recall correctly this started after upgrading my cluster to Kubernetes 1.13 (specifically version `1.13.5-gke`). The issue has persisted after upgrading to `1.13.6-gke.0`. Even creating a new node pool and migrating to it had no effect.

The cluster consists of four nodes with 1 CPU and 3 GB RAM each. I know that's small for a k8s cluster, but this has worked fine in the past.

I am using the new Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring as well as Istio on GKE.

Any pointers as to what could be the reason or where I look for possible causes would be appreciated.

Screenshots of the Node event list (happy to provide other logs; couldn't find anything meaningful in Stackdriver Logging yet):

[image: node event list]
[image: node event list]

Comment: An unhealthy status can mean:

 - A node reports a NotReady status on consecutive checks over the given
   time threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
 - A node does not report any status at all over the given time
   threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
 - A node's boot disk is out of disk space for an extended time period
   (approximately 30 minutes).

try enabling auto repair.

Comment: @Sachith.Wanni I had Auto Repair enabled before and experienced the same issues. That's why I had tried disabling Auto Repair in the first place.

Comment: I would start from posting the `kubectl describe node` maybe there is something going on before your Node gets rebooted and unhealthy. Also do you use resources and limits? Can this restarts be a result of some burstable workload? Also have you tried checking system logs after the restart on the Node itself? Can you post the results?

Comment: Are you still affected by this issue? The default version now is `1.16.13-gke.401`. The issues with node rebooting could be related to the fact of low resources that your nodes are having. The official documentation [states](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#creating_a_cluster_with_istio_on_gke) that you will need 4 nodes (`n1-standard-2`) with 2vCPU and 8GB of RAM. Have you tested your setup/workload on a cluster with bigger resources?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what made that issue go away — could have been upgrading my Kubernetes version or getting rid of Istio. In any case, it works fine now, with just two e2-medium instances.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give some troubleshooting tips/steps as the underlying issue wasn't found.

Feel free to expand it.

After below steps, the issue with a node rebooting were not present anymore:

- Updated the Kubernetes version (`GKE`)
- Uninstalling `Istio`
- Using `e2-medium` instances as nodes.

---

As pointed by user @aurelius:

> I would start from posting the `kubectl describe node` maybe there is something going on before your Node gets rebooted and unhealthy. Also do you use resources and limits? Can this restarts be a result of some burstable workload? Also have you tried checking system logs after the restart on the Node itself? Can you post the results? – aurelius Jun 7 '19 at 15:38

Above comment could be a good starting point for troubleshooting issues with the cluster.

Options to troubleshoot the cluster pointed in comment:

- `$ kubectl describe node` focusing on output in:

  - `Conditions` - `KubeletReady`, `KubeletHasSufficientMemory`, `KubeletHasNoDiskPressure`, etc.
  - `Allocated resources` - `Requests` and `Limits` of scheduled workloads
- Checking system logs after the restart on the node itself:

  - `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Logging` -> `Legacy Logs Viewer`/`Logs Explorer` -> `VM Instance`/`GCE Instance`

It could be also beneficiary to check the `CPU`/`RAM` usage in:

- `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Monitoring` -> `Metrics Explorer`

You can also check if there are any operations on the cluster:

- `gcloud container operations list`

---

Adding to above points:

> #### Creating a cluster with Istio on GKE
>
> We suggest creating at least a **4 node cluster with the 2 vCPU machine type** when using this add-on. You can deploy Istio itself with the default GKE new cluster setup but this may not provide enough resources to explore sample applications.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Istio: Docs: Istio on GKE: Installing](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#creating_a_cluster_with_istio_on_gke)*

Also, the official docs of Istio are stating:

> #### CPU and memory
>
> Since the sidecar proxy performs additional work on the data path, it consumes CPU and memory. As of Istio 1.7, a proxy consumes about **0.5 vCPU per 1000 requests per second.**
>
> -- *[Istio.io: Docs: Performance and scalability: CPU and memory](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/performance-and-scalability/#cpu-and-memory)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Debug cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/)*